# VLC time2clip.lua, extenstion that copies current timestamp to clipboard is formatting wrong

Tags: lua, timestamp, vlc

The extension Time2Clip.lua has been working perfectly for years on my desktop system, but my PC crashed a few days ago and I've been trying to get it to work on my laptop with no luck. Both Time2Clip.lua and time_ext.lua extensions have always had trouble working with newer versions of VLC, neither are working now, but without access to my desktop system, I have no idea what VLC iteration I was on. I've been going through past VLC versions hoping that's the problem, but nothing has worked yet. I'm not sure if I even have the lua code correct and I don't understand the language enough to edit it.

Time2Clip.lua is supposed to return a timecode like 1:23:45, instead it returns 5,025,489,999 (that's actually what 1 hour 23 minutes 45 seconds returns. Microseconds? Excel can't seem to convert it back to hours:minutes:seconds) [Image of extension][1]

Here's the extension:

```
--[[
INSTALLATION:
Put the file in the VLC subdir /lua/extensions, by default:
 Windows (all users): %ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\extensions\
Restart the VLC.
Then you simply use the extension by going to the "View" menu and selecting it.
--]]


function descriptor()
    return {
        title = "Time2Clip";
        version = "1.0";
        author = "valuex";
        url = 'http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php?content=149618';
        shortdesc = "Time2Clip";
        description = "<div style=\"background-color:lightgreen;\"><b>just a simple VLC extension </b></div>";
        capabilities = {"input-listener"}
    }
end
function activate()
    input_callback("add") 
    create_dialog()
end
function deactivate()
    input_callback("del")
end
function close()
    vlc.deactivate()
end
function input_changed()
    input_callback("toggle")
end

callback=false
function input_callback(action)  -- action=add/del/toggle
    if (action=="toggle" and callback==false) then action="add"
    elseif (action=="toggle" and callback==true) then action="del" end

    local input = vlc.object.input()
    if input and callback==false and action=="add" then
        callback=true
        vlc.var.add_callback(input, "intf-event", input_events_handler, "Hello world!")
    elseif input and callback==true and action=="del" then
        callback=false
        vlc.var.del_callback(input, "intf-event", input_events_handler, "Hello world!")
    end
end

function input_events_handler(var, old, new, data)

end

function create_dialog()
    w = vlc.dialog("Time2Clip")
    w1 = w:add_label("<b>CurrentTime:</b>",1,1,1,1)
    w2 = w:add_text_input("0",2,1,1,1)  
    w3 = w:add_button("jumpto", click_SEEK,1,2,1,1)
    w4 = w:add_button("Save_to_Clip", click_SAVE,2,2,1,1)
end

function click_SAVE()
    local input = vlc.object.input()
    if input then
        local curtime=vlc.var.get(input, "time")
        w2:set_text( curtime )
        save_to_clipboard(curtime)
    end
end

function click_SEEK()
    local time_togo = w2:get_text()
    local input = vlc.object.input()
    if input then
        vlc.var.set(input, "time", time_togo)   --jump to specified time
    end
end

function save_to_clipboard(var)
    strCmd = 'echo '..var..' |clip'
    os.execute(strCmd)
end


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/va4aO.png
```

Comment: Maybe delete/comment the last line of your posted code?

Comment: If that not the problem, what i am guessing, then make sure you have ```clip``` installed: https://linux.die.net/man/1/clip